# Get data from a survey paper document

Tags: php, javascript, vb.net, pdf, doc

i know it could sound as a silly question but i was wondering if there's a way to get data from a survey on paper though: i mean, let's say i have a survey on paper with questions and some checkbox that the user will tick and i want to get its data scanning the document and save it as pdf, if it's possible, or jpg or doc, whatever.
Then with PHP or whichever language you suggest, try to get the data in some way from the scanned document and put it to a DB.

Is there a possible way to do that?

Comment: Look into OCR. Then, from there, good luck!

Comment: thanks for the answer i'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract OCR,ocropus might help you